# Return df containing points within radius - python

Tags: python, pandas

There's a few questions on this but I'm getting stuck. I have a `df` that contains coordinates for various scatter points. I want to generate a radius around one of these points and return the points that are within this radius for each point in time. Using the `df` below, I want to return a df that contains all the points within the radius around `A` for each point in time.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
        'Time' : ['09:00:00.1','09:00:00.1','09:00:00.1','09:00:00.1','09:00:00.1','09:00:00.2','09:00:00.2','09:00:00.2','09:00:00.2','09:00:00.2'],                 
        'Label' : ['A','B','C','D','E','A','B','C','D','E'],                 
        'X' : [8,4,3,8,7,7,3,3,4,6],
        'Y' : [3,3,3,4,3,2,1,5,4,2],
        })

x_data = (df.groupby(['Time'])['X'].apply(list))
y_data = (df.groupby(['Time'])['Y'].apply(list))

AX_data = (df.loc[df['Label'] == 'A']['X'])
AY_data = (df.loc[df['Label'] == 'A']['Y'])

def countPoints(df, center_x, center_y, x, y, radius):

    '''
    Count number of points within radius for label A
    '''

    # Determine square distance
    square_dist = (center_x - x) ** 2 + (center_y - y) ** 2

    # Return df of rows within radius
df = df[square_dist <= radius ** 2].copy()

return df

df = countPoints(df, AX_data, AY_data, x_data, y_data, radius = 1)
```

Intended Output:

```
         Time Label  X  Y
0  09:00:00.1     A  8  3
1  09:00:00.1     D  8  4
2  09:00:00.1     E  7  3
3  09:00:00.2     A  7  2
4  09:00:00.2     E  6  2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here my take on it using `np.linalg.norm`

```
def calc_dist(gp, a_label, r=1):
    dist_df = gp[['X', 'Y']] - gp.loc[gp.Label.eq(a_label), ['X', 'Y']].values  
    dist_arr = np.linalg.norm(dist_df, axis=1)

    return gp[dist_arr <= r]


df_A = df.groupby('Time').apply(calc_dist, a_label='A', r=1).reset_index(drop=True)

Out[2159]:
         Time Label  X  Y
0  09:00:00.1     A  8  3
1  09:00:00.1     D  8  4
2  09:00:00.1     E  7  3
3  09:00:00.2     A  7  2
4  09:00:00.2     E  6  2
```

---

**Method 2**:

```
df1 = df.where(df.Label.eq('A')).groupby(df.Time).apply(lambda x: x.ffill().bfill())
m = np.linalg.norm(df[['X', 'Y']] - df1[['X', 'Y']], axis=1) <= 1
df_A = df[m]

Out[2262]:
         Time Label  X  Y
0  09:00:00.1     A  8  3
3  09:00:00.1     D  8  4
4  09:00:00.1     E  7  3
5  09:00:00.2     A  7  2
9  09:00:00.2     E  6  2
```